# Including css files through getDocument doesn't work

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to include some css files through `$document = JFactory::getDocument();` or through `JHtml::stylesheet($stylesheet);` but none of this works. Why it's not working ?

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$reset = '/media/com_event/css/reset.css';
$document->addStyleSheet($reset );
JHtml::stylesheet($reset);
```

I'm adding this files in component's view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the full path using `JUri::root()` like so:

```
$reset = JUri::root() . 'media/com_event/css/reset.css';
$document->addStyleSheet($reset);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Nope, its not working. Can this not be working if files not exist or bad path ?

Comment: does the reset.css actually exist in the folder specified?

Comment: No. I made new joomla instalation and here, everything works fine.

Comment: No, it doesn't depends on if there is or there is no css file. I meant that the link to css file appeared, on new joomla site, while the old is not showing anything.

Comment: I just checked old site's template index.php, `<jdoc:include type="head" />` was missing so I guess this is the reason why files didn't appeared in head section.

Answer (score 0):

Include in your template's `index.php`

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

And it will start working.